# Prevent text from going behind slideshow

Tags: html, css

I have some text, a slideshow and some tabs. I would like my text to wrap around the slideshow on the right, but right now the text is behind the slideshow and I really don't know why.

Could anyone take a look and point me in the right direction?

http://www.emb-ideas.com/index.php/component/smart/?id=155&view=product

Thanks.

Comment: Add width: 520px; to your #description in stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Unfortunately it won't work because once you log in it changes width. What I want is the text to respect the boundary imposed by the slideshow.

Comment: Floating doesn't have an effect when you absolutely position the element. I'd suggest putting your text and your slideshow into a div together, and floating the slideshow to the right without absolute positioning.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Torr3nt, it helped me to figure out an answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a two column layout and should treat it as such. Both columns should be floated left. You can either put an element with clear:both under it or add overflow:hidden to the parent to avoid it collapsing.

Positioning things like this will only lead to problems.

If you don't want to do this you'll have to set a container width as suggested above. if the parent size changes when logging in then set the width as a percentage.

Comment: No problem! Best of luck onwards.